# Sentence Analysis

Tags: punctuation

There are two sentences:

- Pizza, chocolate, and ice cream are my favorite foods.
- Pizza, chocolate, and ice cream - these are my favorite foods.

> Explanation is that a dash can be used to set off an initial position free modifier.

What does 'initial position free' means? I wonder if the two sentences above have different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tangible difference in meaning; just two different ways of saying the same thing.

I've never heard of the expression 'initial position free modifier', but it probably means an adjunct that is not an integral part of the main clause, but loosely attached, and set off by commas or dashes. But that's not the case with your second example where what you have is a series of NPs in pre-nuclear position.

Comment: I think your explanation is better than mine. +1)